A man holds a blonde girl's arm with superglue and they remain like that till the end
It is an action film on the whole with a love scene at the end, I guess. For the large part, it is an action film. I can hardly remember the actors' looks but as far as I can remember, the male lead was middle aged with specs and the girl was a short haired blonde.
I just remember two scenes: One is where the male lead applies superglue in his palm and explains its power to the blonde girl i.e. the female lead. And then, he grabs her hand with his glued palm, and they are stuck like that and travel everywhere throughout the movie. Only in the last scene, they somehow cut it through. I am not even sure if it is a movie or TV series.

Is there any reason for adding action tag? Language/country? release year or decade? how do character looks? Anything else form story?

S.... it is an action film on the whole with a love scene at the end I guess.... For the large part, it is an action film.... I can hardly remember the looks..... As far as I can remember, The male lead was like middle aged with a specs, and the girl was a short haired blonde.....  Thats all I could remember about it.... Sorry if this wudn't help

This is D.O.A. from 1988 with Dennis Quaid and Meg Ryan.

Dexter Cornell, an English Professor becomes embroiled in a series of murders involving people around him. Dexter has good reason to want to find the murderer but hasn't much time. He finds help and comfort from one of his student, Sydney Fuller.

He kidnaps Fuller and glues her hand to his. They're seperated near the end, though (I think she falls). The actors fit your description, too. You might also want to check out the 1950 film this was based on, which IIRC was much better. Here's the (rather grainy) trailer:




"They're seperated near the end, though (I think she falls)." Yes. She falls from scaffolding during an attack using an ..industrial tool.

That's exactly the movie..... Thank u very much

@shab No problem, but don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. That effectively resolves the question.

@Walt sure thing
